# Access to HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in Java Spring Service

Tags: java, spring

I have an emailService implementation in my Java Spring Boot project. To send email, I use JavaMailSender. In my service I need an access to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` in order to instantiate WebContext. Now I am passing these 2 - request and response through my `mailsender` methods what sounds like a bad idea. I would like to have them in my service so I can call methods in my `mailsender` with only 2 variables: what email template to use and a map of variables that will be printed on that email. Is there a way to instantiate request and response in my service? Can I somehow autowire them in the service? Thats how my service looks like:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("MailSender")
public class MailSenderService {

@Autowired 
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Autowired 
private ServletContextTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver;


public boolean sendMail(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     
response, HashMap<String, String> info, String template) throws 
MessagingException, IOException{

    final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper message = new 
    MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true, "UTF-8"); // true = multipart

        message.setFrom("sender@example.com");
        message.setTo("mymail@example.com");
        message.setSubject("This is the message subject");
        TemplateEngine engine = new TemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver);
        WebContext ctx =  new WebContext(request, response, 
        request.getServletContext(), request.getLocale());

        ctx.setVariable("info", info);


    try{        
        String messageContent=  engine.process(template, ctx);
        mimeMessage.setContent(tt, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't be using the request and response and should strive for a solution in which you don't need those. You should be using a default context. Also you shouldn't be recreating the `TemplateEngine` but simply configure that in your context (with the required `TemplateResolver`s) and inject it.

Comment: M.Deinum I really appreciate this hint. Yet I'm not sure how I can do that. Are you suggesting that I should have a separate class that instantiates TemplateResolver once and has request and responce there? I was not able to find any Java email package that can send email template without using request and repsonse btw

Comment: No I'm saying that you should let Spring configure your `TemplateEngine` and just inject that instead of `ServletContextTemplateResolver`. YOu shouldn't bother with the configuration/setup in your mail sending class (it isn't its responsibility). Also you should be using a plain `Context`  and not a `WebContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters your `MailSenderService` shouldn't be bothered with creating the `TemplateEngine` nor know about how to resolve templates, that should be transparant. See [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html) turorial on the Thymeleaf website.

Assuming that you are using XML for bean configuration and Spring 4 add the following. (you probably already have an instance of the `ServletContextTemplateResolver` configured).

```
<bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
  <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
  <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>

<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Engine (Spring3-specific version) -->
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
  <property name="templateResolvers">
    <set>
      <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
      <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
    </set>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Now in your `MailSenderService` you can simply inject the `TemplateEngine`.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("MailSender")
public class MailSenderService {

@Autowired 
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

@Autowired 
private TemplateEngine engine;

    public boolean sendMail(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HashMap<String, String> info, String template) throws MessagingException, IOException{

        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new 
        MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true, "UTF-8"); // true = multipart

        message.setFrom("sender@example.com");
        message.setTo("mymail@example.com");
        message.setSubject("This is the message subject");

        WebContext ctx =  new WebContext(request, response, 
        request.getServletContext(), request.getLocale());

        ctx.setVariable("info", info);

        try{        
            String messageContent=  engine.process(template, ctx);
            mimeMessage.setContent(tt, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Instead of `request.getLocale()` simply use `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` and put all the properties you need in your template in your `info` variable. With this you could rewrite your method to the following.

```
public boolean sendMail(Map<String, String> info, String template) throws MessagingException, IOException{

        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new 
        MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true, "UTF-8"); // true = multipart

        message.setFrom("sender@example.com");
        message.setTo("mymail@example.com");
        message.setSubject("This is the message subject");

        Context ctx =  new Context(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        ctx.setVariable("info", info);

        try{        
            String messageContent=  engine.process(template, ctx);
            mimeMessage.setContent(tt, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        return true;

    }
```

NO need anymore for a `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. Just a plain service. Generally you don't want that your service layer depends on the web as that is what you effectivly did in your solution.

Comment: Thank you M.Deinum! Great instructions

Answer (score 1):

If the class is request scoped you can autowire it as follows :

@Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;

Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to autowire `HttpServletRequest`, though the same doesn't work for `HttpServletResponse`.

eg.

```
@Autowired HttpServletRequest request; // works
@Autowired HttpServletResponse response; // doesn't work
```

There is some discussion about that [here](http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/06/injecting-httpservletresponse-into-spring-mvc-request-scoped-interceptors/) -- though in the end it looks like you may have to pass the response manually.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how i solved it with annotations. Big thanks to M. Deinum !

I finally got it all working. I am not using XML. I work with Spring Boot but if I want to configure something, its all in my configuration methods. For everyone lost like I was, here is my configuration of templateEngine in my @Configuration class:

```
 @Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver(){
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new      
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/emails/");
        emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(1);
        return emailTemplateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(emailTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }
```

With this configuration I can just @Autowire

```
   private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

In my service and now I do not need request, response. Everything works with  Context